# Why does popt segfault when a string is too short?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, popt

Why would popt be segfaulting when the `argDescrip` string isn't long enough?

Take the following example:

```
#include <popt.h>

struct poptOption options[] = {
  POPT_AUTOHELP
  {
    .longName = "color",
    .shortName = '\0',
    .argInfo = POPT_ARG_STRING
               | POPT_ARGFLAG_OPTIONAL
               | POPT_ARGFLAG_SHOW_DEFAULT,
    .arg = (void*) "auto",
    .val = 1,
    .descrip = "Whether or not to use colored output",
    .argDescrip = "always|never|auto (checks if TTY)"
  },
  POPT_TABLEEND
};


int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  // get popt context
  poptContext ctx = poptGetContext(
      "program",
      argc, argv,
      options,
      POPT_CONTEXT_POSIXMEHARDER);

  // parse
  poptGetNextOpt(ctx);

  return 0;
}
```

The above segfaults:

```
/tmp$ ./a.out --help
Usage: a.out [OPTION...]
[1]    47468 segmentation fault  ./a.out --help
```

Although changing `.argDescrip` to

```
.argDescrip = "always|never|auto (checks if TTY) "
              "........................................."
```

popt happily accepts it and displays the output:

```
/tmp$ ./a.out --help
Usage: a.out [OPTION...]
      --color[=always|never|auto (checks if TTY) .........................................]     Whether or not to use colored output

Help options:
  -?, --help                                                                                

Show this help message
    --usage
Display brief usage message
```

What gives? Am I missing something in the C spec? The [popt man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popt) don't specify a required length. Is this a bug?

Comment: What do you mean `"What gives?"`???

Comment: @barakmanos it's [a term](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39947/what-is-the-spelt-out-form-of-what-gives) that means essentially "why is this?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is something else. You have set the `arg` member to a constant string while you would have needed to set it to a pointer to such (the man page says, arg should be initialized with a pointer to `char *`). Your program dies while trying to dereference a pointer that isn't one.

Try like this:

```
char *garg = "auto";

struct poptOption options[] = {
    POPT_AUTOHELP
    {
        .longName = "color",
        .shortName = '\0',
        .argInfo = POPT_ARG_STRING
                | POPT_ARGFLAG_OPTIONAL
                | POPT_ARGFLAG_SHOW_DEFAULT,
        .arg = &garg, 
        .val = 1,
        .descrip = "Whether or not to use colored output",
        .argDescrip = "always|never|auto (checks if TTY)"
    },
    POPT_TABLEEND
};
```

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks! Not sure who downvoted you. I wonder why the string length made the difference. Must be how they're mapping data internally.